# Selecting Column from pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Series named 'graph' in pandas that looks like this:

```
Wavelength
450      37
455      31
460       0
465       0
470       0
475       0
480     418
485    1103
490    1236
495     894
500     530
505      85
510       0
515     168
520       0
525       0
530     691
535     842
540    5263
545    4738
550    6237
555    1712
560     767
565     620
570       0
575     757
580    1324
585    1792
590     659
595    1001
600     601
605     823
610       0
615     134
620    3512
625     266
630     155
635     743
640     648
645       0
650     583
Name: A1, dtype: object
```

I am graphing the curve using graph.plot(), which looks like this :
[image]

The goal is to smooth the curve. I was trying to use the [Savgol_Filter](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html#scipy.signal.savgol_filter), but to do that I need to separate my series into x & y columns. As of right now, I can acess the "Wavelength" column by using graph.index, but I can't grab the next column to assign it as y.

I've tried using iloc and loc and haven't had any luck yet.

Any tips or new directions to try?

Comment: Since this is a `Series` you can just use `y = graph`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass an `x` and a `y` to `savgol_filter`.  You just need the `y` values which get passed automatically when you pass `graph` to it.  What you are missing is the window size parameter and the polygon order parameter that define the smoothing.

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import pandas as pd

# I passed `graph` but I could've passed `graph.values`
# It is `graph.values` that will get used in the filtering
pd.Series(savgol_filter(graph, 7, 3), graph.index).plot()
```

[image]

---

To address some other points of misunderstanding

1. `graph` is a `pandas.Series` and **NOT** a `pandas.DataFrame`.  A `pandas.DataFrame` can be thought of as a `pandas.Series` of `pandas.Series`.
2. So you access the index of the series with `graph.index` and the values with `graph.values`.
3. You could have also done

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   plt.plot(graph.index, savgol_filter(graph.values, 7, 3))
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Series instead of DataFrame, some libraries could not access index to use it as a column.
Use:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

it will convert the index to an extra column you can use in savgol filter or any other.